# Present view from app delegate with a tabbar Controller-> Nav controller -> View Hierarchy - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I have searched throughout S.O and have found similar articles, but none of the solutions worked for me.  Below is a screenshot of my view hierarchy
[image]

One of the many snippets of code I have tried is as follows:

```
            var storyBoard = UIStoryboard()
            if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
                storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "iPad", bundle: nil)
            } else {
                storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            }


            let tabVc = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController


            let mynVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nav") as! UINavigationController


            let calcVc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "destVc")


            tabVc.present(mynVC, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
              // Segue , do stuff

            })
```

The above code presents the correct tab with a nav bar, but there is no tabor present.

I would like to have a force touch button that presents the tab with the navigation bar AND the tabbar present, does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Why is the tab bar view controller presenting the navigation controller? You need to set the navigation controller as the current controller in the tab bar view controller. You probably need to set an array of view controllers on the tab bar view controller where this navigation controller is one of the items in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not able to fully test this at the moment, but I believe that in a tab bar, you dont present the view controller. you set its view controller items and selectedViewController properties.

This should work, I'll test it and update shortly,

```
var storyBoard = UIStoryboard()
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
            storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "iPad", bundle: nil)
        } else {
            storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        }


        let tabVc = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

        let mynVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nav") as! UINavigationController

        let calcVc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "destVc")

        tabVc.viewControllers = [mynVC]
        tabVc.selectedViewController = mynVC
```

Depending on what else you have below, you may also need to call window.setKeyAndVisible() to actually show

Comment: Worked perfectly, I ended up editing tabVc.viewController = [mynVC] to add the other tab in my actual project.  This seems to produce the exact result I was looking for.  Thank you, going to test then mark as accepted answer.

Comment: Great, glad to of helped :) Good luck with the project

Comment: Quick question, if I wanted to show the view controller AND THEN segue to a different one with this implementation.  Would I just call "calcVc.performsegue(withIdentifier: "testSegue", sender: self)" ?

Comment: Yeah you should be able to do that without any issues. As long as the segue is registered